# Cocos2d-x MSVS template install script not found

Tags: visual-studio-2012, cocos2d-x

I've downloaded the stable version of cocos2d-x 2.1.4 to use on Microsoft Visual Studio 2012 Professional.

However, as I run `install-templates-msvc.bat`, running the script causes the following errors:

`Couldn't find script file "<cocos2d-x directory>\cocos2d-x-2.1.4\template\msvc\InstallWizardForVS2012.js"`

`Couldn't find script file "<cocos2d-x directory>\cocos2d-x-2.1.4\template\msvc\InstallWizardForVS2012Express.js"`

Same errors for VS2010 and VS2010Express also appears.

As I search in the template folder in cocos2d-x directory, there is no folder named `msvc`.

So I have 2 questions:

1. I'm wondering why this is happening, because I did not modify a single file from the zipped version of the download (I've also tried downloading it again).
2. Building the solution cocos2d-win32.vc2012 terminates with 2 errors, one for Watermelon something and another for CocosdragonJS. My temporary attempt was to remove them from the solution, but I'm wondering if there are any fancier solution. Perhaps I missed something at installation?

Comment: I guess I could start my project by modifying the HelloCpp in the default solution, but I still think there is a neater way...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try Cocos2dx rc0 2.1.3 It worked for me or copy .txt file in .sln project then remove it. MSVS Ultimate edition automatically fixes the errors.

Answer (score 0):

https://github.com/cocos2d/cocos2d-x/commit/0885d64a20d6862d4e99c381d97acf026654a8a3

[Win32] Deleting vs template, please use 'tools/project-creator' to create multi-platform project instead.